# Within reverse coding in factor analysis, should the wording of the item itself also be reversed for clarification?

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

Say for example you have an item that has a negative factor loading, like this:

**Item 1: I feel emotionally connected with my XBox (-.80)**

Assume item 1 ranges from *1. Strongly Agree* to *7. Strongly Disagree.* If I decide to reverse code it to range from *1. Strongly Disagree* to *7. Strongly Agree*, should I also reverse the wording to make it like

**Item 1r: I DO NOT feel emotionally connected with my XBox,**

or should I leave it alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I realized the answer. If I reverse code the item I shouldn't change the wording of it. If someone scores 7 on item 1, they now score 8-7 = 1 on item 1r. Changing the item would result in a response that isn't correct.